# AndroidViewClient: How access a device when more then one device is connected (For AndroidViewclient 5.1.1)

Tags: androidviewclient

We are having two Android devices connected to PC at the same time. I want to use `wake` and `drag` commands. Till now I was using `AndroidViewclient` version 3.2, which use to work with `monkeyrunner`. So these function were easily automated.

Since there is new version of `AndroidViewClient` (Which is much faster then one latter version), we would like to migrate our scripts.

We have a function which is able to unlock one device. But not working for more than one device. Can you plz help us with same.

Please  find the code:

```
for i in range(len(connected_devices)-1):
    serialno2=connected_devices[i]
    serialno1=connected_devices[i+1]
    device_ref, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(serialno1,1)
    device_dut, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(serialno2,1)
    myBluetooth.Device_Unlock(device_dut,serialno1)

def Device_Unlock(device,serialno):
#To make device Wake up
device.wake()
device.drag((157,662), (642,1163), 1.0, 120)
```

We are not sure how to pass `serialno` to the `Device_Unlock` function

Comment: I found similar question at link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238844/how-to-connect-multiple-devices-using-androidviewclient", but was not able to reply. Hence opened new Question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238844/how-to-connect-multiple-devices-using-androidviewclient%22 answer should work in your case too