# How to make multi-devices dump with AndroidViewClient/dump command?

Tags: android, adb, dump, android-uiautomator, androidviewclient

I'd like to compare the screen of my devices (many) so I'm using AndroidViewClient tool to get the hierarchy of my screens with the `dump` command in a terminal.

However, my devices are all linked with my computer at the same time, and the `dump` command seem to work on only one device. So when I use the command, I get the dump of the first device in the device list when I use `adb devices`.

My goal is to compare screens. So what I want is to specify which device I want to use for my dump in the terminal (and then doing it for all my devices to compare).

Is there a solution of this ? because the only solution I found yet is to make an `adb -s [device serial_number] shell uiautomator dump`, which offer the possibility to chose which device we want to use among those who are attached, but it produce an xml file (and this is why I need AndroidViewClient's dump, because I don't want the xml file).

In other words, is there a way to specify a device with the dump command in a terminal without disconnecting my USBs successively (keep only one device connected at the same time) ?

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20238844/1778421

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I don't understand what is it for ??
I talked about dump command, not the culebra command my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to `dump` different devices that are already available through `adb`.

Getting help you can see that `dump` accepts an optional command line parameter which is the `serialno`

```
$ dump --help
usage: dump [OPTION]... [serialno]
...
```

You can also take a look at `--multi-device` option for `culebra` that can generate tests that run on many devices at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much Diego ! it works !
Sorry, I'm still a beginner with the tool I didn't know the optional command line. By the way, AndroidViewClient is an open source tool right ?